# CSS Problem Simple

Tags: css

I have absolutely no idea why this isn't working. I'm trying to align the navigation and content of a website, navigation is fine at the moment.

**Problem**: Whatever I change in the CSS for content does not affect the class in the other page.

```
<div class='content'>
 aslkdhal;kshl;kasdkjasdhkjlashkjashdkjalsdklajsd
</div>

div.content{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

I'm sure it's simple. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it is simple. 
You just need to specify .content's width.

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

centers the div itself, not the content.

Comment: @nullbyte: if the answer helped you vote and select it as your answer.